# Duplicate entry although everything is working as intended

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem with my database where I have a crosstable created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Spacial_Tasks (
Task_Number Int (11),
FK_Member Int (11),
CONSTRAINT PK_Special_Tasks PRIMARY KEY (Task_Number, FK_Member),
FOREIGN KEY (FK_Memeber) REFERENCES member(Id)
);
```

Now I want this table designed in such a way that for example every moderator of my team gets a certain number für "Task_Number" and the "FK_Member" is the Id of the main table of all members.

Now when I'm putting a new data set in my table, node.js (or the mysql module) throws an error:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Although this error occurrs the new dataset is accepted by my database.

Am I doing something wrong or can I turn this message off in some way?

Comment: How can `0-1` be a value for the primary key when the PK consists of two numbers?  How are you sure that this is being accepted by MySQL?

Comment: what data are you inserting? Are you allowing MySQL to determine the Primary Key by itself, or are you passing it explicitly?
It seems like you insert the same data twice - the first time it inserts OK, and second time gives you this error,

Comment: Task_Number Int (11) how it's being updated? When you do insert in table Task_Number value...you just assume that mysql will do it? or you generate number?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This is one of the Problems. When searching for this Error I have only found a variation with '0' or with '1'.

Comment: @Kleskowy The Data I have inserted the first time was Task_Number: '0' and FK_Member: 4. The second input was Task_Number:'0' and FK_Member:1.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk I always insert a value by myself in Task_Number.
The number represents a Task (for example):
0 = Moderator,
1 = Admin,
2 ...
So its important for me that I control what is in this column

Comment: Then you got the problem on surface. PRIMARY KEY requires to be unique. So every row must have different value. And on your schema you got PRIMARY KEY (Task_Number, FK_Member <- this is also ID that always the same). So for moderator with id 1 you want to add few tasks. And you insert 3 rows with PRIMARY KEY = 0(moderator)-1(id of user) <-- that is huge ERROR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to put together what we have in comments.

[PRIMARY KEY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp) is the unique value for every row in table.

In your example you construct `PRIMARY KEY` from two values `(Task_Number, FK_Member)` .

`FK_Member` - is unique user ID and `Task_Number` is predefined set of values for every task.

Now when you try to insert 3 moderator(0) tasks for some user with id = 155.

Mysql receive this primary keys to save :

```
0155 - first record will be saved as for now its unique
0155 - gives primary key error as value is the same from row number 1
0155 - same error.
```

To fix it you just need to make different primary key, typically its [auto_increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) column

```
CREATE TABLE Spacial_Tasks (
Task_Id Int (11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
Task_Number Int (11),
FK_Member Int (11),
PRIMARY KEY (Task_Id),
FOREIGN KEY (FK_Memeber) REFERENCES member(Id)
);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for beeing all over the place with my explaination. This helped, I will implement it like this. Thank you!